# Given account contributions: How to sum contributions per individual? In relation to a threshold?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Given contribution amounts per account, how do I 1)SUM the contributions made by each individual, 2)Find the number of people who have contributed <, =, or > $5,000?

Right now I have a database table "[dbo].[FakeRRSPs]" which looks like:

[image: Example Database]

- Account_ID
- Personal_ID
- Contributions

My current code gives the # of unique individuals successfully:

```
    select distinct(personal_id), sum(contributions), count(account_id),
      (select count(distinct(personal_id))
      from [dbo].[FakeRRSPs]
      )
    from [dbo].[FakeRRSPs]
    where personal_id is not null
    group by personal_id
```

For example, there are 2M people holding 2.5M accounts.

Issues I face:

- How do I count the number of individuals who contribute below, at, or
  above the $5K threshold (after SUM(contribution) per person)
- There are people who contribute $10K total for example, $5K in 2
  accounts. Both accounts are picked up when I'm hoping to only capture
  the SUM(Contribution) for this person.

I hope this is clear enough - it certainly isn't to me! Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  This sounds like a basic `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6d73/5)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Contribution (PID int,AID int,C int)
insert into Contribution(PID,AID,C)VALUES(235,1245,1200)
insert into Contribution(PID,AID,C)VALUES(256,1246,0)
insert into Contribution(PID,AID,C)VALUES(256,1247,3500)
insert into Contribution(PID,AID,C)VALUES(256,1248,10000)
insert into Contribution(PID,AID,C)VALUES(421,1249,0)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from (select PID,sum(C) AS SC from Contribution
group by PID) as test
where test.SC<=5000
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6d73/5/0)**:

```
| PID |   SC |
|-----|------|
| 235 | 1200 |
| 421 |    0 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I realize it's a simple thing for this group but I appreciate the assistance.